# Can Unix shell be used to report completion status in some manner?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ksh

I have seen some ideas for progress bars around SO and externally for specific commands (such as cat).  However, my question seems to deviate slightly from the standard...

Currently, I am using the capability of the `find` command in shell, such as the follow example:

```
find . -name file -exec cmd "{}" \;
```

Where "cmd" is generally a zipping capability or removal tool to free up disk space.
When "." is very large, this can take minutes, and I would like some ability to report "status".

Is there some way to have some type of progress bar, percentage completion, or even print periods (i.e., Working....) until completed?  If at all possible, I would like to avoid increasing the duration of this execution by adding another `find`.  Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, you can only have a progress meter or percent completion if you know how long the command will take to run, or if it can tell you that it has finished x tasks out of y.

Here's a simple way to show an indicator while something is working:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "launching: $@"
spinner() {
    while true; do
        for char in \| / - \\; do
            printf "\r%s" "$char"
            sleep 1
        done
    done
}
# start the spinner
spinner &
spinner_pid=$!
# launch the command
"$@"
# shut off the spinner
kill $spinner_pid
echo ""
```

So, you'd do (assuming the script is named "progress_indicator")

```
find . -name file -exec progress_indicator cmd "{}" \;
```

Comment: Right, so do you have an idea of how to determine number tasks, "y", without significantly increasing runtime? Unfortunately, 'code'find'code' takes an exceptionally long time to enumerate files.. Perhaps the 'du' command would work?  I will update after some more research.  For now, this seems like a great workaround for me.  I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: This seems to print a progress indicator for each file it does operations on.  Is there anyway to extend this to the whole find command?  In other words, can this code be altered in some way to not print a new spinner for each file that is found, but rather for the entire operation of find?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `dialog` utility installed (), you can easily make a nice rolling display:

```
find . -type f -name glob -exec echo {} \; -exec cmd {} \; |
dialog --progressbox "Files being processed..." 12 $((COLUMNS*3/2))
```

The arguments to `--progressbox` are the box's title (optional, can't look like a number); the height in text rows and the width in text columns. `dialog` has a bunch of options to customize the presentation; the above is just to get you started.

`dialog` also has a progress bar, otherwise known as a "gauge", but as @glennjackman points out in his answer, you need to know how much work there is to do in order to show progress. One way to do this would be to collect the entire output of the find command, count the number of files in it, and then run the desired task from the accumulated output. However, that means waiting until the find command finishes in order to start doing the work, which might not be desirable.

Just because it was an interesting challenge, I came up with the following solution, which is possibly over-engineered because it tries to work around all the shell gotchas I could think of (and even so, it probably misses some). It consists of two shell files:

```
# File: run.sh

#!/bin/bash
# Usage: run.sh root-directory find-tests
#
# Fix the following path as required
PROCESS="$HOME/bin/process.sh"
TD=$(mktemp --tmpdir -d gauge.XXXXXXXX)
find "$@" -print0 |
tee >(awk -vRS='\0' 'END{print NR > "'"$TD/_total"'"}';
      ln -s "$TD/_total" "$TD/total") |
{ xargs -0 -n50 "$PROCESS" "$TD"; printf "XXX\n100\nDone\nXXX\n"; } |
dialog --gauge "Starting..." 7 70 
rm -fR "$TD"

# File: process.sh

#!/bin/bash
TD="$1"; shift
TOTAL= 
if [[ -f $TD/count ]]; then COUNT=$(cat "$TD/count"); else COUNT=0; fi
for file in "$@"; do
  if [[ -z $TOTAL && -f $TD/total ]]; then TOTAL=$(cat "$TD/total"); fi
  printf "XXX\n%d\nProcessing file\n%q\nXXX\n" \
         $((COUNT*100/${TOTAL:-100})) "$file"
  #
  # do whatever you want to do with $file
  #
  ((++COUNT))
done
echo $COUNT > "$TD/count"
```

Some notes:

There are a lot of gnu extensions scattered in the above. I haven't made a complete list, but it certainly includes the `%q` printf format (which could just be `%s`); the flags used to NUL-terminate the filename list, and the `--tmpdir` flag to `mktemp`.

`run.sh` uses `tee` to simultaneously count the number of files found (with `awk`) and to start processing the files.

The `-n50` argument to `xargs` causes it to wait only for the first 50 files to avoid delaying startup if find spends a lot of time not finding the first files; it might not be necessary.

The `-vRS='\0'` argument to `awk` causes it to use a `NUL` as a line delimiter, to match the `-print0` action to `find` (and the `-0` option to `xargs`); all this is only necessary if filepaths could contain a new-line.

`awk` writes the count to `_total` and then we symlink `_total` to `total` to avoid a really unlikely race condition where `total` is read before it is completely written. symlinking is atomic, so doing it this way guarantees that `total` either doesn't exist or is completely written.

It might have been better to have counted the total size of the files rather than just counting them, particularly if the processing work is related to file size (compression, for example). That would be a reasonably simple modification. Also, it would be tempting to use `xargs` parallel execution feature, but that would require a bit more work coordinating the sum of processed files between the parallel processes.

If you're using a managed environment which doesn't have `dialog`, the simplest solution is to just run the above script using `ssh` from an environment which does have `dialog`. Remove `| dialog --gauge "Starting..." 7 70` from run.sh, and put it in your `ssh` invocation instead: `ssh user@host /path/to/run.sh root-dir find-tests | dialog --gauge "Starting..." 7 70`

Comment: How would your answer change in regards to the total size of the files?    Would that slow execution if the total size is GBs?  This is precisely what I was looking for, but it seems my externally managed environment does not include the 'dialog' command.  I will have to come up with another solution.

Comment: To make the second solution work with file size, you'd need to replace the `-print0` with something like `-printf "%s/%p\0"` (which will print the size as well as the name, separated by a `/` and still terminate with a `NUL`. Then the `awk` invocation would need to be something like `awk -vFS=/ -vRS='\0' "{s+=$1}END{print s}"` and in the processing loop you'd need to remove the size, by adding `filename=${file#.*/}`. You'd also have to come up with a reasonable starting total size value somehow. I edited the answer about `dialog`

Comment: Oops. `filename="${file#*/}"`

Comment: @bts: also, there are a variety of other dialog-like programs, including, for example, whiptail and tcdialog.

Comment: I do indeed have whiptail.  I'm assuming that it has a very similar implementation, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The trick with find is that you add two `-print` clauses, one at the start, and
one at the end.  You then use `awk` (or `perl`) to update and print a line counter for each
unique line.  In this example I tell awk to print to stderr.

Any duplicate lines must be the result of the conditions we specified, so we treat that special.
In this example, we just print that line:

```
find . -print -name aa\* -print |
awk '$0 == last {
    print "" > "/dev/fd/2"
    print
    next
}
{
    printf "\r%d", n++ > "/dev/fd/2"
    last=$0
}'
```

It's best to leave find to just report pathnames, and do further processing from awk,
or just add another pipeline.  (Because the counters are printed to stderr, those will not
interfere.)